# Python Groupby with Boolean Mask

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with the following general format:

```
id,atr1,atr2,orig_date,fix_date
1,bolt,l,2000-01-01,nan
1,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan
1,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,stem,l,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
3,bolt,r,2000-01-01,nan
3,stem,r,2000-01-01,nan
3,bolt,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
3,stem,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
```

This result would be the following:

```
id,atr1,atr2,orig_date,fix_date,failed_part_ind
1,bolt,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
1,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
1,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
2,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan,1
2,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
2,stem,l,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
3,bolt,r,2000-01-01,nan,1
3,stem,r,2000-01-01,nan,1
3,bolt,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
3,stem,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
```

Any tips or tricks most welcome!

**Update2:**

A better way to describe what I need to accomplish is that in a `.groupby(['id','atr1','atr2'])` to create a new indicator column where the following criteria are met for records within the groups:

```
(df['orig_date'] < df['fix_date'])
```

Comment: The first 3 conditions don't seem to make any sense whatsoever....

Comment: Agreed.  What I am getting at is that in the context of say a .groupby(['id']) create an indicator column on each record where (df['atr1'] == df['atr1']) &
(df['atr2'] == df['atr2']) & (df['orig_date'] < df['fix_date'])

Comment: It still doesn't make sense unfortunately, I'm not sure how that code would get you to your expected output. Can you explain?

Comment: @coldspeed Apologies again for the confusion.  I think Eric Wang's answer is on the right track.  I think a groupby on id, atr1, atr2 and then a transform compatible operation to check the date logic to produce the indicator is the best way forward.  I'm working on my end as well.

Comment: Eric Wang's answer works for me.  A vectorized approach would be great though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
df['failed_part_ind'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if ((row['id'] == row['id']) &
                                                (row['atr1'] == row['atr1']) &
                                                (row['atr2'] == row['atr2']) &
                                                (row['orig_date'] < row['fix_date']))
                                            else 0, axis=1)
```

**Update:** I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np
def f(g):
    min_fix_date = g['fix_date'].min()
    if np.isnan(min_fix_date):
        g['failed_part_ind'] = 0
    else:
        g['failed_part_ind'] = g['orig_date'].apply(lambda d: 1 if d < min_fix_date else 0)
    return g

df.groupby(['id', 'atr1', 'atr2']).apply(lambda g: f(g))
```

Comment: unfortunately, the date comparison does not seem to work as intended.  thanks for the contribution.,

Comment: @Pylander So are you trying to compare the 'orig_date' and 'fix_date' of the rows that have same 'id', 'atr1', and 'atr2'?

Comment: @Pylander I've updated my answer with my best guess of what you are trying to get. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: This seems to be more on track I think.  I had to substitute np.isnat since that is a datetime value.  Now I am encountering an "TypeError: invalid type promotion"

Comment: I managed to get this to run by substituting pd.isnull() for np.isnat().  First run seemed to produce duplicate records.  Double checking now.

Comment: This would appear to work as intended.  Thanks for your help.