# Python Groupby Function Vectorized

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I posted a previous question ([Python Groupby with Boolean Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092924/python-groupby-with-boolean-mask)) which provided a successful answer:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """ 
id,atr1,atr2,orig_date,fix_date
1,bolt,l,2000-01-01,nan
1,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan
1,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan
2,stem,l,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
3,bolt,r,2000-01-01,nan
3,stem,r,2000-01-01,nan
3,bolt,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
3,stem,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01
"""
data = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=['orig_date', 'fix_date'])

def f(g):
    min_fix_date = g['fix_date'].min()
    if pd.isnull(min_fix_date):
        g['failed_part_ind'] = 0
    else:
        g['failed_part_ind'] = g['orig_date'].apply(lambda d: 1 if d < min_fix_date else 0)
    return g

df.groupby(['id', 'atr1', 'atr2']).apply(lambda g: f(g))
```

This result would be the following:

```
id,atr1,atr2,orig_date,fix_date,failed_part_ind
1,bolt,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
1,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
1,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
2,stem,l,2000-01-01,nan,1
2,screw,l,2000-01-01,nan,0
2,stem,l,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
3,bolt,r,2000-01-01,nan,1
3,stem,r,2000-01-01,nan,1
3,bolt,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
3,stem,r,2001-01-01,2001-01-01,0
```

However, I am now trying to develop an optimized/vectorized version to improve the runtime and scale up to larger datasets.  Any tips or trick would be most welcome!  I'm currently experimenting with pandas `.idxmin()` and numpy `.argmin()`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
df.groupby(['id','atr1','atr2']).apply(lambda x: (x.orig_date < pd.to_datetime(x.fix_date.min()))
                                .astype(int)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!  Unfortunately, this does not appear to work for me after adapting it.  I wonder if there might be a related .groupby transform approach? I'll have to revisit this.